# Do we say "heavily invested into the stock" or "heavily invested into the stocks"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Do we say

> "heavily invested into the stock"

or

> "heavily invested into the stocks"?

Let's say you buy 100 Apple stocks, do you say "I am heavily invested into the stock" or "I am heavily invested into the stocks"? Or is the entire sentence wrong? I feel the word "stock" can refer to so many things and it can be confusing at times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stock = part of the ownership of a company which people buy as an investment - you have stock in a company.

Stocks = the multiples of the parts - you own parts in more than one company.

Stock is the capital of a company raised through the issue and subscription of shares. There may be one or many stock holders in a company. If there is more than one stockholder, then each has one part of the stock.

Equally, a person may own stock in a number of different companies, so he has several stocks.

"I am heavily invested in Apple stock"

Comment: This is plain wrong, at least in the US. If you own 100 shares of Apple, you do not say that you own stocks in Apple. You say that you own shares of Apple.

Comment: Did you read carefully? I didnt say "I am heavily invested in Apple stocks" I said "I am heavily invested in Apple stock". If you are in the US or not shares can be collectively called stock.

Comment: Oh, I read quite carefully. It is easy to imply falsely that I did not after you changed your original post. You originally said that you should use the word "stocks" if you own more than one part of a company  in other words, you *were* advising to say "stocks" if you owned 100 shares. I did not downgrade your original post because you are new. I shall resist the temptation to downgrade your revised post because it no longer has the error I originally pointed out. In the future, however, I shall simply downgrade your posts if they are erroneous regardless of your newness.

Comment: When I check the edits it doesn't show stocks as you said. Maybe you need to clean your'e reading glasses. I'm just going to ignore you, you seem too emotionally invested in answering these questions.

Comment: btw I didn't downvote you. No negativity for me!

Comment: upvote for you my friend you need it. And apparently a hug too. :)

Comment: "Stocks = the multiples of the parts - you have more than one part" is what you originally wrote.

Comment: I do admit that was confusing but that still didn''t mean what you are implying. Given by the fact that you chose to copy part of the sentence I wrote. "Stocks = the multiples of the parts - you have more than one part or you own parts in more than one company." And the next paragraph explains the difference between shares and stocks. So as I said earlier if you read my answer as a whole. English or any other language needs to be read in context. You are trying to get all the information from one sentence when it clearly makes more sense when you read the whole answer. Peace mate have a g'day.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is odd.

You are correct that "stock" has a variety of meanings (which are best explicated historically). But the "stock" of a corporation is viewed as a collective noun. It is true that a corporation can have any number of shares authorized or outstanding, but each one represents a pro-rata interest in the corporation's "undivided capital," to use an old-fashioned but useful legal term. The word "stock" in the parlance of the stock market refers, unless qualified, to the aggregate of a single corporation's shares outstanding. So the word you want in this context is "stock." "Stocks" would refer to shares of more than one corporation.

Moreover, the usual preposition used with "invest" is "in" rather than "into."

> I invested in Apple's stock

is idiomatic in US English.